# Docker .NET (not core) using Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm try to publish a docker container in AWS ECR/ECS using an Azure Devops Pipeline.
so what do I do:

1. I created an asp.NET WebApi project (not core)
2. I added the dockerfile from Visual Studio 2019 (I haven't changed
   the default file)
3. I pushed to a repos in azure devops
4. I created a build pipeline for building the solution
5. I added a docker build operation to the pipeline
6. Try to Push Image to AWS ECR

The result is that until the solution build everything is working, but when I try to build the docker I have a Copy error (this is the log):

```
Starting: build
================================================== ============================
Task: Docker
Description: Build or push Docker images, login or logout, or run a Docker command
Version: 2.162.0
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Help: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker
================================================== ============================
"C: \ Program Files \ Docker \ docker.exe" build -fd: \ a \ 2 \ s \ xxx\ xxx\ Dockerfile --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamfoundationcollectionuri = https: // dev. azure.com/yyy/ --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamproject = InRule --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.name = xxx-backend --label com.azure.dev .image.build.sourceversion = 3580bfefbe0592212a1d9c76c6d30dd472e22748 --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.uri = https: //ggg@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxx-backend .azure.dev.image.build.sourcebranchname = develop --label "com.azure.dev.image.build.definitionname = In WebApi Release Docker rule" --label com.azure.dev.image.build.buildnumber = 20200204.12 - -label com.azure.dev.image.build.builduri = vstfs: /// Build / Build / 11456 -t xxx d: \ a \ 2 \ s \ yyy\ yyy
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072kB

Step 1/13: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
 ---> a5bc996f06b3
Step 2/13: ARG source
 ---> Running in f385f2f0cc47
Removing intermediate container f385f2f0cc47
 ---> 525c70129725
Step 3/13: WORKDIR / inetpub / wwwroot
 ---> Running in a8b464b080f2
Removing intermediate container a8b464b080f2
 ---> 534984f17fd7
Step 4/13: COPY $ {source: -obj / Docker / publish}.
COPY failed: CreateFile \\? \ C: \ ProgramData \ docker \ tmp \ docker-builder949209785 \ obj \ Docker \ publish: The system cannot find the path specified.
## [error] The process 'C: \ Program Files \ Docker \ docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: build
```

My pipeline YAML code is:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller @ 0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand @ 2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: XXXSolution.sln

- task: VSBuild @ 1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: XXXSolution.sln
    msbuildArgs: '/ p: DeployOnBuild = true / p: WebPublishMethod = Package / p: PackageAsSingleFile = true / p: SkipInvalidConfigurations = true / p: PackageLocation = "$ (build.artifactstagingdirectory) \\"'
    platform: '$ (BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$ (BuildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts @ 1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$ (build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$ (Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  enabled: false
  condition: succeededOrFailed ()

- task: ExtractFiles @ 1
  displayName: 'Extract files'
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$ (build.artifactstagingdirectory) /XXX.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$ (build.artifactstagingdirectory) / XXX / XXX / obj / Docker / publish'

- task: Docker @ 2
  displayName: build
  inputs:
    command: build
    Dockerfile: XXX / XXX / Dockerfile
    arguments: '-t XXX'

- task: CopyFiles @ 2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $ (build.artifactstagingdirectory) / obj / Docker / publish'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$ (build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$ (build.artifactstagingdirectory) / obj / Docker / publish'
  enabled: false

- task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.ECRPushImage.ECRPushImage@1
  displayName: 'Push Image:'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: awsCredentials
    regionName: 'eu-west-1'
    sourceImageName: XXX
    repositoryName: XXX

- task: PublishSymbols @ 2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '** \ bin \ ** \ *. Pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  enabled: false
  continueOnError: true
```

Can anyone help me to understand where the error is?

Comment: Hi ActiveDev, how about this issue, have you figured out it?

Comment: Hi ActiveDev, any update on this issue, Did you get a chance to implement the solution that *Alexandre Nourissier* suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I think your tasks "Docker@2" and "CopyFiles@2" are inverted.

If you look at the docker log, you can see that Docker expects to find the publish output inside a \obj\Docker\publish folder but you only copy them there after the Docker@2.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new log after change the order of the tasks:

```
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4589916Z ##[section]Starting: build
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4701538Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4701659Z Task         : Docker
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4701727Z Description  : Build or push Docker images, login or logout, or run a Docker command
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4701805Z Version      : 2.162.0
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4701860Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4701927Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker
2020-02-07T10:45:04.4702016Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-07T10:45:04.8198317Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" build -f D:\a\1\s\XXX\XXX\Dockerfile --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamfoundationcollectionuri=https://dev.azure.com/XXX/ --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamproject=XXX --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.name=XXX-backend --label com.azure.dev.image.build.sourceversion=3580bfefbe0592212a1d9c76c6d30dd472e22748 --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.uri=https://XXX@dev.azure.com/XXX/XXX/_git/XXX-backend --label com.azure.dev.image.build.sourcebranchname=develop --label "com.azure.dev.image.build.definitionname=XXX WebApi Release Docker" --label com.azure.dev.image.build.buildnumber=20200207.1 --label com.azure.dev.image.build.builduri=vstfs:///Build/Build/11467 -t XXX D:\a\1\s\XXX\XXX
2020-02-07T10:45:11.7158942Z Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
2020-02-07T10:45:11.7159461Z 
2020-02-07T10:45:11.7600295Z Step 1/13 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
2020-02-07T10:45:11.7698947Z  ---> a5bc996f06b3
2020-02-07T10:45:11.7699194Z Step 2/13 : ARG source
2020-02-07T10:45:12.2010655Z  ---> Running in e5d56a7c6647
2020-02-07T10:45:14.4009801Z Removing intermediate container e5d56a7c6647
2020-02-07T10:45:14.4010663Z  ---> 298dd53c140a
2020-02-07T10:45:14.4011018Z Step 3/13 : WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
2020-02-07T10:45:14.4463513Z  ---> Running in e44696a950d4
2020-02-07T10:45:15.9378724Z Removing intermediate container e44696a950d4
2020-02-07T10:45:15.9379138Z  ---> e6e8d9c8ab53
2020-02-07T10:45:15.9380224Z Step 4/13 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
2020-02-07T10:45:15.9380626Z COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\tmp\docker-builder901134993\obj\Docker\publish: The system cannot find the path specified.
2020-02-07T10:45:15.9467650Z ##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
2020-02-07T10:45:15.9528776Z ##[section]Finishing: build
```

Comment: As I said,  "Docker expects to find the publish output inside a \obj\Docker\publish folder" but your copy step in the docker file doesn't point to the right folder. You need to change the argument of step 4.